# Dirichlet coefficients as limits: wrong

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, series-expansion

Perhaps I should have included the word "bug" in my question. Here we go

There is a bug in this Limit

```
Limit[3^s (-1 - 2^-s + Zeta[s]), s -> ∞]
(* 0 *)
```

which should be 1.

But I **withdraw** herewith (16 July, 2015) my former statement (8 July, 2015) that there is a bug in a specific Series[].

More elaboration below.

Trying to calculate coefficients of a Dirichlet series $f(s)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } a( n) n^{-s}$ using `Limit[]` reveals a strange behaviour of Mathematica 10.1

Here's a simple example.

Let

```
f[s_]:=Zeta[s]
```

and

```
b[n_, s_] := n^s (f[s] - Sum[1/k^s, {k, 1, n - 1}])
```

then we would expect to get the first four Dirichlet coefficients from

```
{Limit[Zeta[s], s -> ∞], 
 Limit[2^s (-1 + Zeta[s]), s -> ∞], 
 Limit[3^s (-1 - 2^-s + Zeta[s]), s -> ∞], 
 Limit[4^s (Zeta[s] - 1 - 2^-s - 3^-s), s -> ∞]}
```

But the output is

```
(*
{1, 1, 0, -∞}
*)
```

The first two limits are ok, the third and fourth limits are wrong, as they must be 1 as well.

On the other hand, plotting b[n,s] shows that the limits are 1.

What's going on here?

Remark:
The standard procedure to calculate the Dirichlet coeffients of a given function f(s) employs this formula

```
a[n_]:= n^σ Limit[(1/(2 T)
      Integrate[f[σ + I t] n^(I t), {t, -T, T}]), 
   T -> ∞]
```

For details see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30975/dirichlet-series-expansion-of-an-analytic-function

But I wanted to take a seemingly simpler approach.

*Expansion of Dirichlet series with the function Series[]*

It is interesting to study the expansion of a Dirichlet series with the function Series[], and especially about the point about `s = ∞`. I shall confine the explication here to the case of the famous Riemann zeta function.

The documentation of Series[] points out as an issue:

Some functions cannot be decomposed into series of power-like functions:

```
Series[Zeta[s], {s, \[Infinity], 10}]

(*
Out[26]= 1 + 2^-s + 3^-s + 4^-s + 5^-s + 6^-s + 7^-s + 8^-s + 9^-s + 10^-s
*)
```

Now consider this limit for various numbers n of expansion terms

```
Table[{n, Limit[Series[2^s (Zeta[s] - 1), {s, \[Infinity], n}] // Normal, 
   s -> \[Infinity]]}, {n, 0, 3}]

(*
Out[36]= {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}}
*)
```

That is, if we wish to collect terms up to s^k we need to Series[] expand up to ar least k. Sorry for pointing out "trivialities", but we are not dealing with well known power series here.

The next example show the importance of this rule more drastically

```
Table[{n, Limit[
   Series[3^s (Zeta[s] - 1 - 2^-s), {s, \[Infinity], n}] // Normal, 
   s -> \[Infinity]]}, {n, 0, 5}]

(*
Out[38]= {{0, -\[Infinity]}, {1, -\[Infinity]}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}}
*)
```

Comment: To help with diagnostics: try expanding the expressions you have as a series at infinity.

Comment: @J.M.:  Ok I'll add it. I did that already for myself before posting hoping to get some insight. But see for yourself.

Comment: I only have *gedanken Mathematica* at the moment, which is why I was asking you to try it for me… :)

Comment: Nice term "gedanken Mathematica" ;-)

Comment: I get the same results in *Mathematica* version 8. @J.M. I also tried Gedanken *Mathematica* version 8, but it crashed my kernel...

Comment: I think it really is a bug. Numerically, one can get it to work by using e.g. this: `SequenceLimit[Table[N[3^s (-1-2^-s+Zeta[s]),20],{s,10,30}]]`.

Comment: Bug fixed in 10.4 (not sure if it had been fixed in an earlier version)

Answer (score 5):

I have found a simple method to mitigate the limit bug:
using an intermediate Series[], the Dirichlet coefficients of a function f[x] can be calculated correctly as a Limit[].

The formulas for the coefficients are

```
cD := Module[{},
  a[1] = Limit[f[x], x -> ∞];
  a[n_] := 
   a[n] = Limit[
     Series[n^x (f[x] - Sum[a[k] k^-x, {k, 1, n - 1}]), {x, ∞, 
        n}] // Normal, x -> ∞]]
```

Example 1: Zeta[x]

```
ClearAll[f, a]
f[x_] := Zeta[x]
cD
t = Table[{n, a[n] }, {n, 1, 10}]

(*
Out[41]= {{1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}, {7, 1}, {8, 1}, {9, 1}, {10, 1}}
*)
```

Example 2:   1/Zeta[x]

```
ClearAll[f, a]
f[x_] := 1/Zeta[x]
cD
t = Table[{n, a[n], MoebiusMu[n] }, {n, 1, 10}]

(*
Out[45]= {{1, 1, 1}, {2, -1, -1}, {3, -1, -1}, {4, 0, 0}, {5, -1, -1}, {6, 1, 1}, {7, -1, -1}, {8, 0, 0}, {9, 0, 0}, {10, 1, 1}}
*)
```

Example 3: Zeta[2 x]/Zeta[x]

```
ClearAll[f, a]
f[x_] := Zeta[2 x]/Zeta[x]
cD
t = Table[{n, a[n] , LiouvilleLambda[n]}, {n, 1, 10}]

(*
Out[50]= {{1, 1, 1}, {2, -1, -1}, {3, -1, -1}, {4, 1, 1}, {5, -1, -1}, {6, 1, 1}, {7, -1, -1}, {8, -1, -1}, {9, 1, 1}, {10, 1, 1}}
*)
```

Example 4: DirichletEta[x]

```
ClearAll[f, a]
f[x_] := DirichletEta[x]
cD
t = Table[{n, a[n] }, {n, 1, 10}]

(*
Out[9]= {{1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 1}, {4, -1}, {5, 1}, {6, -1}, {7, 1}, {8, -1}, {9, 1}, {10, -1}}
*)
```

Example 5: RamanujanTauL[x] not applicable

```
ClearAll[f, a]
f[x_] := RamanujanTauL[x]
```

Method not applicable because both

```
Limit[RamanujanTauL[x], x -> ∞]

(*
Out[19]= Limit[RamanujanTauL[x], x -> ∞]
*)
```

and

```
Series[RamanujanTauL[x], {x, ∞, 2}]

(*
Out[20]= RamanujanTauL[x]
*)
```

Are returned unevaluated.

Observations

1) This method to calculate the Dirichlet coefficients is limited by the ressources of the machine and those of Mathematica.

2) Cross reference
[What are the terms of the sequence generated by Zeta(3s)/Zeta(s)?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/77711/what-are-the-terms-of-the-sequence-generated-by-zeta3s-zetas/77731#77731) (March 19, 2015)
Here I have used the naive limit approach for the first time.

Comment: Does your approach work on `DirichletEta[]` and `RamanujanTauL[]`?

Comment: @J.M.: I have included these examples in my answer.

Comment: Wunderbar! Danke!

Comment: My pleasure !               .

Comment: I have revised my original question.

Comment: @Dr.WolfgangHintze I would really appreciate a detailed explanation of cD. If you would prefer such, I can make a new question for it, please let me know.

Comment: @nilo de roock Oh, that is 5 years ago, and I thought the code speaks for itself. Now please tell me what you have tried so far and where you got stuck. By the end of the week I have Mathematica available and will have a look on your progress.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will write up what I understand and what not and post it.