# Why doesn't Mathematica evaluate this simple limit?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I want to evaluate $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(n-\sqrt{\sin(n)+10n+n^2}\right)^2$$

I used this code

`Limit[(n - Sqrt[Sin[n] + 10 n + n^2])^2, n -> \[Infinity]]`

It returns unevaluated. This limit is not hard to calculate by hand so I'm a bit surprised. Why doesn't *Mathematica* evaluate it?

Comment: `Limit` code is not dealing well with that `Sin[n]` term. It uses `Series` which really has no "nice" representation for sine at infinity. Would be good to replace it with `Interval[{-1,1}]` maybe (I mean in the `Limit` code, not at the user end).

Comment: The result from Maple 2015 limit((n-sqrt(sin(n)+10*n+n^2))^2, n = infinity) is 25, but Maple 16 give incorrect result: infinity!

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I see that's the core of the problem. Thanks for your comment (+1)

Comment: Mathematica also gives some interesting numerical answers. Take n->10^7 and //N; you get 25. Take n -> 10^10 and you get 0.

Comment: @Calchas I just checked it and you are right. Weird...

Comment: Interestingly, `Limit[(n - Sqrt[10 n + n^2 + Sin[x]])^2, n -> ∞, Assumptions -> -1 <= Sin[x] <= 1]` quickly produces 25

Comment: @Calchas That numeric behavior is a straightforward consequence of machine arithmetic cancellation error.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Are you saying it's working as intended and expected? ;)

Comment: @Calchas The numeric evaluation, yes. I am assuming you did something equivalent to this: `N[(n - Sqrt[Sin[n] + 10 n + n^2])^2 /. n -> 10^18]`. Also note that if you use 10^10 in the replacement it actually gives 25. If you did something else then I may have misunderstood the comment re "interesting numerical answers".

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Nope 10^10 gives me 0. 10^9 gives me 0.5ish. Is variation across systems also a feature? ;)

Comment: @Calchas It certainly could be, although I'm surprised to see that large a difference. Might have to do with usage, or not, or extended precision registers (which is certainly platform dependent). Look up "cancellation error" and you might get an idea of what is happening.

Comment: @ m_goldberg: 1) very convincing, and probably the least help effort to MMA, and, what's more, a completely justified one. Could even overwrite my recent answer. Sorry for having noticed your comment so late. 2) Unfortunately, it does not work for a general bounded function: Limit[f[n]/n, n -> \[Infinity],  Assumptions -> -1 <= f[n] <= 1] is returned unevaluated instead of giving 0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On a different occasion ([Dirichlet coefficients as limits: wrong](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87766/dirichlet-coefficients-as-limits-wrong)) I have shown that the sometimes limited capabilities of the function `Limit[]` can be improved by using an intermediate `Series[].`

Following this idea we can write for the limit in question

```
Limit[Expand[
  Normal[Series[(n - n Sqrt[1 + x])^2, {x, 0, 2}]] /. 
   x -> 10/ n + Sin[n]/n^2], n -> \[Infinity]]

(* 25 *)
```

In this manner we can even calculate the limit with a symbolic parameter "a"

```
Limit[Expand[
  Normal[Series[(n - n Sqrt[1 + x])^2, {x, 0, 2}]] /. x -> a/ n + Sin[n]/n^2],
  n -> \[Infinity]]

(* a^2/4 *)
```

Also, a general function is permissible (provided `Limit[f[n]/n,n -> \[Infinity]] == 0`)

```
Limit[
 Expand[Normal[Series[(n - n Sqrt[1 + x])^2, {x, 0, 2}]] /. 
   x -> a/ n + f[n]/n], n -> \[Infinity]]

(* Limit[a^2/4 + 1/2 a f[n] + f[n]^2/4, n -> \[Infinity]] *)
```

Where the final Limit can only be assessed once f[n] is given explicitly.

*Modification of the OP*.

Taking `f[n] = Sin[n]` (instead of `f[n] = Sin[n]/n` as in the OP) we find

```
Limit[Expand[
  Normal[Series[(n - n Sqrt[1 + x])^2, {x, 0, 2}]] /. x -> a/ n + Sin[n]/n], 
 n -> \[Infinity]]

(* Limit[a^2/4 + 1/2 a Sin[n] + Sin[n]^2/4, n -> \[Infinity]] *)
```

Taking the x-expansion beyond x^2 we get for all higher powers

```
Limit[Expand[
  Normal[Series[(n - n Sqrt[1 + x])^2, {x, 0, 3}]] /. x -> a/ n + Sin[n]/n], 
 n -> \[Infinity]]

(* 1/4 (a + Interval[{-1, 1}])^2 *)
```

Comment: Always very informative and interesting; +1

Comment: I agree with Sektor. A very instructive answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

The problem here is the `Sin[n]` which **has no limit** since it is an oscillating function, but it is always **bounded** by $\pm 1$: if you change you code with the following:

```
Limit[(n - Sqrt[1 + 10 n + n^2])^2, n -> Infinity]
```

with 1 in place of `Sin` (or -1 if you want), you get the result:

```
(*25*)
```

Comment: Like in `Limit[n - Sqrt[10 n + n^2 + a], n -> \[Infinity],  Assumptions -> -1 < a < 1]`

Comment: Thanks. So it appears `Sin[n]` is the problem... Changing the code in that way indeed gives the correct answer, but you shouldn't have to do that :/. As a side note and as it's been mentioned in the comments, Maple 2015 evaluates the limit with no problem. _Mathematica_ has some "catching up" to do...

Comment: Should be reported as a bug

Comment: `Limit[(n - Sqrt[1 + 10 n + n^2])^2, n -> \[Infinity],  Assumptions -> -1 <= a <= 1]`  @Dr. belisarius

Answer (score 5):

Since the functionality of `Limit[]` has been improved in version 11.2, the limit is now evaluated rather easily:

```
Limit[(n - Sqrt[Sin[n] + 10 n + n^2])^2, n -> ∞]
   25
```